# Problem with changing the secret key in docker/superset

Tags: docker, apache-superset, secret-key

I have a problem when changing the secret and it doesn't work nothing. I change in the file `superset/config.py` the `SECRET KEY` for one created with `openssl rand -base64 42` and below I write `PREVIOUS_SECRET_KEY` with my old `SECRET KEY1`.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nbs9x.png)

I save and exit. Next, I ran a pull and an up:

```
-docker-compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml pull
-docker-compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml up -d
```

Once the updated successfully, I ran the migration with an error:
`-docker exec -it superset_app superset re-encrypt-secrets`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMq4e.png)

I don't understand it and I don't know what to do.

I have also tried different combinations with the `SECRET KEY` in the file `superset/config.py` and nothing has worked.

Comment: Hy, welcome to Stack Overflow, please [don't upload text, table or error message as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. 
Also see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: [link to the docs](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/configuring-superset/#rotating-to-a-newer-secret_key)

Comment: Have answered this here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76626514/a-default-secret-key-was-detected-please-use-superset-config-py-to-override-it/78164595#78164595](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76626514/a-default-secret-key-was-detected-please-use-superset-config-py-to-override-it/78164595#78164595)

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to find a fix for your problem? If not then you can try this:

In your superset_config.py file, make two entries as below:

```
PREVIOUS_SECRET_KEY = 'your previous secret key'
SECRET_KEY = 'your new secret key'
```

your existing secret key will be visible in constants.py file