# A Default SECRET_KEY was detected, please use superset_config.py to override it. Getting this error in docker apache superset

Tags: docker, ssl-certificate, apache-superset

I am getting this error though `SECRET_KEY` is added to `superset_config.py` to enable SSL in dockerized Apache Superset.

```
A Default SECRET_KEY was detected, please use superset_config.py to override it.
Use a strong complex alphanumeric string and use a tool to help you generate
a sufficiently random sequence, ex: openssl rand -base64 42
Refusing to start due to insecure SECRET_KEY.
```

Adding the configuration files

```py
CELERY_CONFIG = CeleryConfig
#ENABLE_DEBUG_LOGGING = True
DEBUG = True
FLASK_APP = "superset"
FLASK_ENV = "debug"

FEATURE_FLAGS = {"ALERT_REPORTS": True,"EMBEDDED_SUPERSET": True}
ALERT_REPORTS_NOTIFICATION_DRY_RUN = True
# CORS Options
ENABLE_CORS = True

# When proxying to a different port, set "x_port" to 0 to avoid downstream issues.

ENABLE_PROXY_FIX = True
HTTP_HEADERS = {"X-Frame-Options": "SAMEORIGIN", "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff"}
ENABLE_SSL = True
SSL_CERT_PATH = "/etc/ssl/certs/server.crt"
SSL_KEY_PATH = "/etc/ssl/certs/server.key"
PROXY_FIX_CONFIG = {"x_for": 1, "x_proto": 1, "x_host": 1, "x_port": 1, "x_prefix": 1}
WEBDRIVER_BASEURL = "http://superset:8088/"
# The base URL for the email report hyperlinks.
WEBDRIVER_BASEURL_USER_FRIENDLY = WEBDRIVER_BASEURL

SQLLAB_CTAS_NO_LIMIT = True
SECRET_KEY ="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

print("Config file loaded successfully!")
print("SECRET_KEY:", SECRET_KEY)
```

The below command is also tried to supress arning, same issue.

```
docker run -d -p 8443:8443 -e SUPPRESS_WARNING_MESSAGE=True apache/superset
```

Answer (score 3):

run this command in shell to change the secret key

```
export SUPERSET_SECRET_KEY="some_random_base64_string"
```

You can create some_random_base64_string using this command in shell

`openssl rand -base64 42`

Answer (score 0):

There can be two scenarios when this can happen.

1. Your previous version had a secret key that was explicitly set
2. Your previous version did not have a secret key that was explicitly set

The first step is to find the existing secret key.

**For Scenario #1**

- If using pip install, navigate to your superset_config.py and locate the value there
- If using the docker install, then look for the value in `.env`

**For Scenario #2**

- If using pip install, with a virtual env, then activate the venv and open the shell using:

> ```
> #Open shell
> superset shell
> #Print Secret key
> from flask import current_app; print(current_app.config["SECRET_KEY"])
> ```

- If using the docker install, the open the docker container using
  `sudo docker exec -it superset_app bash` then run the same shell command as above.

Now that ***you have your secret key***, open the superset_config.py of the new env you are setting and adding the following lines:

> ```
> PREVIOUS_SECRET_KEY = ‘Paste the key you just found’
> SECRET_KEY = ‘Add your new key’
> ```

Save and exit. Then run the following commands

> ```
> superset db upgrade 
> superset re-encrypt-secrets
> superset init
> ```